# How to check if rune is valid?

Tags: string, go, utf-8

I'm trying to make Reverse function in Go. However by reversing bytes it can be invalid rune. How to handle this situation?

```golang
func Reverse(input string) string {
    builder := strings.Builder{}
    builder.Grow(len(input))

    for i, w := len(input)-1, 0; i >= 0; i -= w {
        r, width := utf8.DecodeLastRuneInString(input[:i+1])
        w = width
        builder.WriteRune(r)
    }

    return builder.String()
}
```

If I try to write runes as is, it has unexpected result, but I want to return an error

Comment: why not iterate over the runes in the string instead of the bytes with `[]rune(input)`

Comment: @HenryWoody, you don’t need the `[]rune` conversion, a for-range loop already iterates over runes.

Comment: Note that even with icza's fix your code doesn't work on all valid Unicode texts: Think e.g. of combining characters.

Answer (score 0):

[`utf8.DecodeLastRuneInString()`](https://pkg.go.dev/unicode/utf8#DecodeLastRuneInString) documents that if the encoding is invalid, it returns `RuneError, 1`. You may check that and decide what you want to do then:

```
func Reverse(input string) string {
    builder := strings.Builder{}
    builder.Grow(len(input))

    for i, w := len(input)-1, 0; i >= 0; i -= w {
        r, width := utf8.DecodeLastRuneInString(input[:i+1])
        w = width
        if r == utf8.RuneError {
            fmt.Println("Invalid rune at", i)
            continue
        }
        builder.WriteRune(r)
    }

    return builder.String()
}
```

Testing it:

```
fmt.Println(Reverse("Hello, 世界"))
fmt.Println(Reverse("Hello,\xff 世界"))
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/6tA5zSq4FGR)):

```
界世 ,olleH
Invalid rune at 6
界世 ,olleH
```

Also note that you can write that loop without variables, just reslice the `input` variable:

```
for len(input) > 0 {
    r, size := utf8.DecodeLastRuneInString(input)
    input = input[:len(input)-size]
    if r == utf8.RuneError {
        fmt.Println("Invalid rune at", len(input))
        continue
    }
    builder.WriteRune(r)
}
```

This outputs the same, try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/I_wFvJMgeoB).